# Create linq query as string

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a string that contains a linq query and i have a dynamic where clause also as string that contains many dynamic condition 
here is my where clause

```
string strWhereString = "where a.id==1 && a.name==\"something\"";
```

and here is my linq query string :

```
var query = "from a in context.tblName "+strWhereString;
```

the question is how to run this query and get result from the table?
Is there any way to do that or Linq doesn't support this ?

Comment: Linq queries must be strongly typed in compile time, you can't do it like you do SQL queries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is something like [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com)

which will give you the possibility to translate a query like:

```
var query = from p in northwind.Products
                where p.CategoryID == 3 && p.UnitPrice > 3
                orderby p.SupplierID
                select p;
```

into:

```
var query = northwind.Products
                         .Where("CategoryID = 3 AND UnitPrice > 3")
                         .OrderBy("SupplierID");
```

also here is a good starting point, which has a good blog post and some examples to download.

[Dynamic LINQ (Part 1: Using the LINQ Dynamic Query Library)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'll have more luck using the linq static methods:

```
context.tblName.Where(a=>a.id==1 && a.name=="something")
```

This way is really easy to add where clauses (or other) dynamically:

```
context.tblName..Where(a=>a.id==1 && a.name=="something").Where(a=>otherClause(a))
```

I'm not sure if this is really what you're looking for, but I think this is the right direction.

Comment: is it possible to add condition to the where clause like a string ?
i mean like this 
 context.tblName.Where("some condtion")

Comment: No, it needs to be strongly typed. What is your use case exactly?

Comment: I mean putting where clause like this 
context.tblName..Where("SERIAL_NUMBER == xxx && MAC==xxx")

i tried but it doesn't accept it

Comment: I understood what you meant. But why do you need to have the clause passed as a string?

Comment: because my clause came from a form like a filter this is the reason i want to make it like this

Comment: this works 

 var query = context.tblname.Where("SERIAL_NUMBER = \"xxx\" && MAC= \"xxx\"").Select("SERIAL_NUMBER");

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I also had to deal with dynamic conditions for doing a DB search. Instead of string parsing or dynamic LINQ, I came up with this solution. `errorsOnly`, `startDate` and `endDate` can (but must not) be set in the frontend. Additional conditions can simply be added accordingly:

```
var query = from x in db.DoubleDataValueArchive select x;
query = query.Where(x => x.DataPointId != null);

// Check if only errors should be shown (that are listed in errorDps)
List<int> errorDps = new List<int>();
if (errorsOnly.HasValue) {
    if (errorsOnly == true)
    {
        errorDps = db.DataPoints.Where(x => x.DataType == 4).Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        query = query.Where(x => errorDps.Contains((int)x.DataPointId));
    }
}

// Start Date
if (startDate.HasValue) {
    startDate = startDate.Value.ToUniversalTime();
    query = query.Where(x => x.DateValue >= startDate);
}

// End Date
if (endDate.HasValue)
{
    endDate = endDate.Value.ToUniversalTime();
    query = query.Where(x => x.DateValue <= endDate);
}
```

...and so on. This is completely dynamic but safe to work with at the same time. The assembled SQL query only gets finally executed once, when you make a list or similar out of the `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Dynamic LINQ. This is a library provided by the LINQ team itself.

What you need to do is use string expressions instead as shown in this blog - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

Comment: Thanks now i am working with this library and trying to find a solution from it.

Comment: @Younisbarznji If this has answered your question then please mark it as the answer and close this topic.